# Применение графического фильтра к изображению с помощью html5

Tags: gwt, canvas, javascript, java, html5

В проекте используется GWT, но в данном случае он служит лишь оберткой для JavaScript кода, работающего с `canvas`. Поэтому буду одинаково рад решению как на GWT, так и на JavaScript.

Задача состоит в следующем: у нас есть входное изображение, которое загружено и отрисовано на канвас, и этот канвас прикреплен (`attached`). По клику мы должны применить графический фильтр. Для этого нужно взять входное изображение `inputImage`, применить к нему фильтр, а затем вывести результат в другое изображение `outputImage`. Я написал такой код:

```
// канвас для выходного изображения
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(Document.get().createCanvasElement()); 
Context2d context2d = canvas.getContext2d(); 
// элемент входного изображения
ImageElement imageElement = ImageElement.as(inputImage.getElement()); 
context2d.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height); 
ImageData data = context2d.getImageData(0, 0, width, height); 
CanvasPixelArray array = data.getData(); 
for (int i = 0; i < array.getLength(); i = i + 4) { 
  // применяем фильтр, для примера я перевожу изображение в оттенки серого
  int silver = (array.get(i) + array.get(i + 1) + array.get(i + 2)) / 3;
  array.set(i, silver); 
  array.set(i + 1, silver); 
  array.set(i + 2, silver); 
} 
context2d.putImageData(data, 0, 0); 
outputImage.setUrl(canvas.toDataUrl("image/png"));
```

Он отлично работает в Хроме и в Сафари, но не работает в Мозилле и в IE9. При этом в IE9 падает исключение:

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (Error): Unknown failure
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
> at com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.ImageData$.getData$(ImageData.java)

То есть `Internet Explorer 9` ругается на строчку

```
CanvasPixelArray array = data.getData();
```

При попытке модифицировать код, например, заменив проход по `CanvasPixelArray` на проход непосредственно по `ImageData` исключение в IE не падает, но приложение ничего не выводит в `outputImage`.

А в Мозилле:

> com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE): Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
> [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
> at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
> at com.google.gwt.canvas.dom.client.Context2d$.drawImage$(Context2d.java)

Мозилла же ругается на попытку вывести `outputImage` на основной канвас с помощью метода `drawImage`.

Каким образом можно заставить этот код работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не используйте метод `getData()`, он не работает в IE. Следует работать с данными изображения через методы класса [`ImageData`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/canvas/dom/client/ImageData.html). Можно заменить

```
CanvasPixelArray array = data.getData(); 
for (int i = 0; i < array.getLength(); i = i + 4) { 
  // применяем фильтр, для примера я перевожу изображение в оттенки серого
  int silver = (array.get(i) + array.get(i + 1) + array.get(i + 2)) / 3;
  array.set(i, silver); 
  array.set(i + 1, silver); 
  array.set(i + 2, silver); 
}
```

на

```
for (int j = 0; j < data.getHeight(); j++) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < data.getWidth(); i++) { 
  // применяем фильтр, для примера я перевожу изображение в оттенки серого
    int silver = ((data.getRedAt(i, j) + data.getGreenAt(i, j) + data.getBlueAt(i, j)) / 3 + 128) / 2; 
    data.setRedAt(silver, i, j); 
    data.setGreenAt(silver, i, j); 
    data.setBlueAt(silver, i, j); 
  } 
}
```

По поводу FF - такое исключение падает, когда изображение еще не загружено. Перенесите код, откуда падает исключение, в обработчик события `onload`.